# Overriding custom templates in a theme

Tags: 7, theming

I am having trouble creating/registering custom templates in a module and overriding them in a theme. For example, I have this in my_module_theme():

```
$theme['contact-page'] = array(
    'render element' => 'content',
    'template' => 'contact-page',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/templates',
    'variables' => array('form' => NULL),        
);
```

This will correctly pick up the template (contact-page.tpl.php) located in modules/my_module/templates as expected. However, if I try to override this template in themes/my_theme/templates it will not be detected.

Furthermore, the advice from some similar questions I have found researching this topic says to use underscores when invoking hook_theme, as such:

```
$theme['contact_page'] = array(
    'render element' => 'content',
    'template' => 'contact-page',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/templates',
    'variables' => array('form' => NULL),        
);
```

When I do this the template (contact-page.tpl.php) is not read at all from either location (modules/my_module/templates or themes/my_theme/templates). In reports->recent log messages I see that Drupal is looking in the right place but cannot find the template for some reason.

Note: I am also rebuilding the theme registry on each page load.

Comment: I have it working now... In this case, there are 3 things that must agree for a particular template to load: the theme array element key must have underscores, the actual template name must use dashes AND when invoking the theme using theme() or drupal_render() the theme name must use the exact same string as the theme array key, which would have used underscores in the example above.